# Can someone help me understand how Spring can be used to create prototype instances?

Tags: java, spring

If the beans are configured through XML, then the input parameter to its constructor is always same, so even if I declare the scope as prototype the members in class's instance will be same for all objects? So, how is it prototype?

As an example, if I have a class whose constructor takes an integer argument:

```
A(int i){}
```

if I configure it through XML bean, won't the value of parameter `i` be hard-coded there? Or is there a way I can pass different values to `i` each time I need to instantiate the class?

Comment: then what is the use of having a prototyped instance?

Comment: Sure there is. Just wire the constructor parameter to a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html). Not sure what the annotation equivalent is, I left Javaland before that became a Thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide values when using getBean directly.  For a more elegant solution, look up 'method injection' in the spring docs.

```
<bean id="beanA" class="A" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Integer" value="null"/>
</bean>

A bean = (A) applicationContext.getBean("beanA", new Object[]{someInteger});
```

Answer (score 1):

All the instances would be the same just after creation. But if they are stateful, then they won't be the same after some operations.

Of course, if your bean is stateless, I don't see any advantage make it a prototype.

Concerning your last question, using SpringEL, you could for instance call a method which returns a different values each time. That way every instance are different after creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare as many prototypes as you want for the same class:

```
<bean id="beanNegative" class="MyBean" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Integer" value="-1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="beanPositive" class="MyBean" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="beanNeutral" class="MyBean" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

Only **value="-1", value="1", value="0"** and the name of the prototype changes.

Naturally, it becomes impossible to do auto-wiring by class from the moment you have more than an instance of that class: you will need to explicitely specify which prototype instance you want to inject in you dependent beans.

Also notice, a prototype is different from a singleton in the fact that each time the bean is get from spring, it is a new instance whereas a singleton will provide the same instance to all other beans in your app.

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi - http://1vu.fr